# Android Bluetooth Low Energy disconnect request not sent?

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth

We're attempting to disconnect from a peripheral, but using a Bluetooth sniffer, we are not seeing an `LL_TERMINATE_IND` packet. Instead the phone appears to keep sending `Empty PDU`s to the peripheral for about another 20 seconds.

We are using the following Cordova BLE plugin: https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central

The disconnect method is here: https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#/L74

We have also tried adding an explicit `gatt.disconnect()` before `gatt.close()` as below, but it appeared not to make any difference:

```
public void disconnect() {
    connectCallback = null;
    connected = false;
    if (gatt != null) {
        gatt.disconnect();
        gatt.close();
        gatt = null;
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant `adb` log. There is an error in the adb log "Context not found" which could be related? Although that appears to be just *after* onDisconnected().

```
04-15 16:25:34.931 24199 24199 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(79263)] "ble:store       > Handle dispatch DOOR_DISCONNECT", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/bundle.js (79263)
04-15 16:25:34.931 24199 24199 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(79263)] "ble:connecting  > § 20", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/bundle.js (79263)
04-15 16:25:34.932 24199 24274 D BluetoothGatt: close()
04-15 16:25:34.932 24199 24274 D BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=5
04-15 16:25:34.933  1886  9721 D BtGatt.GattService: unregisterClient() - clientIf=5
04-15 16:25:34.934  1886  2019 W bt_btif : bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=3 connected=0 conn_id=3 reason=0x0016
04-15 16:25:34.934  1886  2019 W bt_btif : bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=4 connected=0 conn_id=4 reason=0x0016
04-15 16:25:34.934  1886  2019 W bt_btif : bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=5 connected=0 conn_id=5 reason=0x0016
04-15 16:25:34.944  1886  1924 D BtGatt.GattService: onDisconnected() - clientIf=5, connId=5, address=00:A0:00:00:00:14
04-15 16:25:34.944  1886  1924 E BtGatt.ContextMap: Context not found for ID 5
04-15 16:25:34.948 24199 24199 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(79270)] "ble:connecting  > _disconnectFromDoor success", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/bundle.js (79270)
04-15 16:25:34.952 24199 24199 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(79263)] "ble:store       > Handle dispatch DOOR_DISCONNECT_SUCCESS", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/bundle.js (79263)
```

And here is what the bluetooth sniffing looks like (with lots more of the same):

[image: Bluetooth sniffer output in Wireshark]

There is a chance that the peripheral has gone to sleep at this point (it's doing that for battery life purposes). That would kind of make sense to me why the phone just keeps sending `Empty PDU`s, but shouldn't we still see the disconnect request over the airwaves?

Comment: My brilliant colleage @ggordan figured this out. I'll leave him to write an answer, but the problem was that we needed to wait for the disconnect to complete successfully (by waiting for onConnectionStateChange with STATE_DISCONNECTED) before closing the connection. As for the Bluetooth sniffing, it's worth noting that it's not 100% reliable and may miss things.